# How to do auto verify OTP like Whats'up in Recharge App in IONIC2

Tags: ionic2

I used for Getting SMS of OTP and for list of SMS Cordova SMS plugin.

I got List of Smses but I want a Latest sms in my textbox and auto verify the OTP.

Comment: can you share the code what you have tried so far

Comment: I solved my issue.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```js
getSMS(sms)
  {

    if(window.SMS)window.SMS.listSMS({},data=>
    {
      setTimeout(()=>{console.log(data);
       this.otp =data;
        if(Array.isArray(this.otp)) {

                for(let i in this.otp) 
                {
                   var msg = this.otp[i];
                      let msgaddress = msg.address;
                     let msgbody = msg.body;
                     var newValue = msgbody.slice(0,34);

                     if(msgaddress == "VK-POCKET" || msgaddress == "VM-POCKET"  && newValue == "your pepocket registration otp is:")
                     {

                          var newVal = msgbody.substring(34,msgbody.length);

                           this.otpname=newVal;
                      }
                     }


                }

       },0 )
    },error=>
    {
      console.log(error);
    });


  }
```